# Remove product add to cart button everywhere

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to remove add to cart button from WooCommerce everywhere and leave it only in single product page

I have made a lot of research and I tried this code but it doesn't work

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );
```

i want users can only add a product to cart in each single product page

Comment: that code should work, unless your theme creates the button in a different way - Where are you putting this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php to do that -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'remove_add_to_cart_from_all_listing', 99, 3 );
function remove_add_to_cart_from_all_listing( $add_to_cart, $product, $args ){
    if( is_product() ) return $add_to_cart;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if your code doesn't work with the hook then you can do hide by css as well